# How to calculate sum for group of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Could you please help me to make query in SQL Server 2012? I have got example data like in a table below.

> code price 
>   p1  1,00 
> p2 1,00
>  p3 1,00 
> p4 1,00
>  p1 2,00
>  p3 2,00
>  p2 4,00

I need to get sum(p1), sum(p2), sum(other) like

```
p1 3.00
p2 5.00
other 4.00
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: you can use space as well for line breaks

Answer (score 1):

You can use from case when in your query:

```
CASE WHEN code NOT IN ('p1', 'p2') THEN 'Other' ELSE code END
```

You obviously also need this as the expression in the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN code NOT IN ('p1', 'p2') THEN 'Other' ELSE code END AS NewCode, 
SUM(price) 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY CASE WHEN code NOT IN ('p1', 'p2') THEN 'Other' ELSE code END
```

Comment: I think this line `NOT IN ('aaa', 'bbb')` should be `NOT IN ('p1', 'p2')`